# Creating multiple table with different prefix but with same table name

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a task to create a PostgreSQL database that has the same table name(e.g. patient, patient_visit, patient_diagnosis) but to be generated multiple time when a different group of users accessing it. For example, users from clinic A will access the 3 table that belongs to them only such as clinicA_patient, clinicA_patient_visit, clinicA_patient_diagnosis, then when users from clinic B access the system they will use other 3 table that belongs to them only such as clinicB_patient, clinicB_patient_visit, clinicB_patient_diagnosis.

It also means if I have 100 clinics, means I will have 300 tables. I want the data to be separated.

Initially, I am thinking about using different schema for a different group of users, but I can't find a solution where Hibernate can generate different schema but with similar table name such as similar @entity annotation? Or is there any way to do it? Does Hibernate have such function that allows auto-generated prefix in creating tables?

Comment: Also, in the end, I want to able to consolidate the data into a data warehouse by end of the month. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: That sounds like a horrible design

Comment: Not only does it sound like a bad design, seems like a big functional hole as well. What happens when a patient goes to clinicA and subsequently goes to clinicB. How can a user at either clinic see the complete patient history?

Comment: I would say the clinic might not want to share their patient data with another clinic until being authorized, thus having a separated table for each of the clinic. Not sure if there is a design that allows separated table for each different clinic and perhaps end of each month will be extracted out and combine in one big table table for long term storage.